# Onepage-scroll: Custom onepage-pagination colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagination, onepage-scroll

The [Onepage-scroll plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll).

In the css files that come with the plugin the pagination has been styled by default. I would like to change the background- and border-color to match every section/page in my project.

Every section has a different background-color and font-color. Im trying to match the pagination to each font color.

This is the code i wrote. It checks if the *plugin* added the class **'active'** to the **'body ul li a'** element, wich the plugin adds automaticaly. Then i get the **'href'** of **this** element and use it to store the **css 'color' value** in a variable. Now i grab the **".onepage-pagination li a:before"** elements, wich come out of the onepage css file.
And then i add my own css background and color values to all these elements.

The problem seems to be that the plugin crashes when i try to change one of it's defaults.

```
       if ($("body ul li a").hasClass('active')) {
            var link_href = $(this).attr('href');
            var color = $(link_href).css('color');
            $(".onepage-pagination li a:before").css({
                "background": color,
                "border": '1px solid' + color;
            });
        };
```

Where did i go wrong?

```
$("body ul li a").data() - returns 'object {index: 1}' in console
```

Would it be possible to use this data attribute in my own css to add style?

Comment: `$(this).attr('href');` wont return a DOM element but the value of the href attribute. That said, you can't do `$.css` on a string value, there is no meaning. Also, consider to insert a blank space just after the `solid` word, otherwise it would try to apply: `'border': '1px solid#ff6600'` for example.

Comment: @Fabiano Araujo. $(this).attr('href'); returns "#1" in the console.

Comment: $(".onepage-pagination li a::before").css('border', '1px solid red !important'); ------ allsow doesn't work ?

Comment: $("body ul li a").data() returns 'object {index: 1}' in console.